# FileOuputStream Write bytes for loop, but no data write?

Tags: java, file-io, fileoutputstream

Listing my program fragment as below

```
public class InStream {

    static FileOutputStream file=null;
    static {
        try {
            file = new FileOutputStream("deo.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
                   //when i try to replace below infinite loop, 
                   //it is also not able to output my String
                    //while(ture)
                        or
                     //for(;;)

            for(int i=0;i<100000;i++){
                file.write("AB ".getBytes());
            }

                 //file.flush(); 

            file.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Run this program -> open deo.txt -> there are no data within this file

but when i comment the for loop just only test below fragment code:

```
   try {
            file.write("AB ".getBytes());
            file.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now i can see the "AB " string  in the file. so strange....

Can any one do me a favor?

Comment: Did you try *with* `file.flush();`?

Comment: as i know  FileOutputStream does not have a relevant feature about flush, if you indeed do that it only invoke its parent's empty method which does not implement anything

Comment: Ok. Which version of java are you using? On which OS? When I try your code, I do see 100000 `AB` in the file. Also, when you use a infinite loop like `while(true)`, you may not see the string because you never close the stream.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in your code. File "deo.txt" must be generate which contains AB AB...............

Comment: Ohh~~ yes when i open it use editplus, it really contains my output string, but when i open it in my eclipse workspace, i can not find anythinh, Ohh~~ Forget it, anyway thinks your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code. And it works. But for the deo.txt. You can check its size if it is about 293k. It displays nothing if you open it with Eclipse text editor. But you can view it with other system editor, such as notepad++.